# Possible ? Can i using "PHP -S localhost" reading with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-services

Can i use some special text in command prompt for reading `.htaccess` file with `php -S`  service build-in with my project

Example : `~/project> $ php -S localhost:8000 -read .htaccess` in my project for check variable `$_GET['url']` for control route redirect to some file.

### Possible way ?

**My mini project :**

- This my project directory

```
project
   |- src
   |- index.php
   |- .htaccess
```

- Code in `.htaccess` file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

- Code in `index.php` file :

```php
<?php

$url = $_GET['url'];

if ($url == "hello") {

    // go to hello file

} else {

    // go to other file

}

?>
```

Comment: Requests for not physically existing files are routed to a index.php or index.html in the current folder automatically, and if neither of those is found, it continues checking the parent folder (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) You will not automatically get a GET parameter though, you will have to find the originally requested URL inside $_SERVER.

Comment: If you implement the above, you can use the same logic later on, when the whole thing runs on a "real" web server, that uses .htaccess files / can do rewriting. Just rewrite to index.php without any parameters then, or use the [`FallbackResource`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) directive instead.

Answer (score 1):

`htaccess` is specific to Apache server. It doesn't work with the PHP built-in webserver.

Comment: You have way ? for solve this problem ? by without .htaccess file

Comment: Well in PHP you can [set a `Location` header to go to another file](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php.php). But...why don't you just use Apache? You won't be using the PHP built-in server when you make your site live. If you test with Apache as well, you'll get a more accurate reproduction of how the live system will work.